# Generic callback parameter pairs in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a React TypeScript component, `Wrapper`, using `forwardRef()`.  The component has a generic parameter `T extends Kind`, where `Kind` is an enum with values `btn` and `div`.  (This is a simplified example, and my use case is not as frivolous as this.)  `Wrapper` simply looks at `props.kind` and returns a `<Div />` or a `<Btn />`, and so its props and ref types depend on `T`.  Following the example given by [TypeScript + React: Typing Generic forwardRefs](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-generic-forward-refs/), I wrote:

```tsx
const Btn = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>(
    (props, ref) => <button {...props} ref={ref} />
);
const Div = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>(
    (props, ref) => <div {...props} ref={ref} />
);

enum Kind {
    btn,
    div,
}

type WrapperPropsType<T extends Kind> = 
    & { kind: T } 
    & (T extends Kind.btn ? ComponentProps<typeof Btn> : ComponentProps<typeof Div>);

type WrapperArgs<T extends Kind> = {
    [Kind.btn]: [props: WrapperPropsType<Kind.btn>, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>];
    [Kind.div]: [props: WrapperPropsType<Kind.div>, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>];
}[T];

const isBtnPropRefPair = (args: WrapperArgs<Kind>): args is WrapperArgs<Kind.btn> => 
    args[0].kind === Kind.btn;

const _Wrapper = <T extends Kind>(...args: WrapperArgs<T>) => {
    if (isBtnPropRefPair(args)) {
        const {kind, ...props} = args[0];
        return <Btn {...props} ref={args[1]} />
    } else {
        const {kind, ...props} = args[0];
        return <Div {...props} ref={args[1]} />
    }
};

export const Wrapper = forwardRef(_Wrapper);
```

Everything works until I wrap it in `forwardRef()`.  It expects `kind` to be `Kind.btn & Kind.div`, which is obviously not going to work.  It also compiles without an error when I try to instantiate it with mismatched props and ref.

```tsx
const Foo = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
    // @ts-expect-error
    return <Wrapper ref={ref} kind={Kind.div} />
};
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible in the current version (5.0.4) of TypeScript?  If so, how do I fix it?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL7YCuAzkpXAL4FQQhwDkUqGnA3AChQkWHBgBPMElxwAwu0gA7JEpgAFNmFrYAYsVJkkFJFTgAJACoBZADIBBGDCjAARtRhJazVuy490GAFBQTQIJVp4ACEYJTgAXgIDckoAHis7KI8YcIBRABskEFUsCxsHJxd3T1p08qynPMLitQA+VoAKDrAtHTgefABKBNa4VOqcuJwAOlmeiG0WAficAZYAelbBoTCI+AARYAA3BKSoEhTTOrtDo4KikuwMiuc3Dy9r21v7lph2rvm2mwA2G8VGqTIx1ws2mgNoS1MKzWcE22xCqmoHAA0sAlGRcII4ES4K5YphCcTIUdyUwQpJpHAAOpQFBgaRQTQLWiWKRIVKWOBIAAenjx3hxeNGiQpRIAZLIANa4sgALjgApYMrg8o6AuForI4uV01JcQA-PJFOESpztKl6UgIPg4DElKM1QpwNa1Lbag6nXBblshIIHUyWWykFB7FAAOa1PUi1SGuASshSgnEuAAbTTJtiAF01dm4Wrmaz2b6edJUnnTa1gaY1fpzoZjGlng1Jj8Sq0C0Is7njVSiznS+GK1Gq7za8Pjg3+k24C2LkYTPhPt9mr3+4ImNnLLvQuFInBgLRXbbKOoUMAoKcOqR42WI+yY-HZ5LBmqn95zxPI2jONajrWIpVGX9swABgLaYlTxBJ4kSUClBDXZTwAfXLQDTn5QUkzFVNlU6GFfxfScgI-SwthGTNiWAZ0OnPS8tGvW8oEfYDBmGHAtSzdD4BweCyGwGE4RYRJIJggcs2JHgYGoKA4lSV1oTmXoEXwFZIIARgLDZWi1FgkHyeg6NkuABNwYTRPUrkJLgKTdwsol5MU5TbjU2ENMXLScF0-SUUMrNaSYENhVEeArOw9lTkIVtLnwDosNfKM0WPPZlwgCAH1BUZeP4k94AGU46AYK5O2yJoHjaDolGofJ8jRLN1nWOAAAEYFoABaCKkAwXqoDYKAtTcpSxhiqNfKRUwWGElY8ypAy934IA)

Comment: Does this question depend on react? If so we should probably tag it as such. If not you might want to [edit] the example code to remove the apparent dependency so it's a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround: don't use a generic; simply use function overloads.

```tsx
function _Wrapper(props: WrapperPropsType<Kind.btn>, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>): JSX.Element;
function _Wrapper(props: WrapperPropsType<Kind.div>, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>): JSX.Element;
function _Wrapper(...args: WrapperArgs<Kind.btn> | WrapperArgs<Kind.div>) {
    if (isBtnPropRefPair(args)) {
        const {kind, ...props} = args[0];
        return <Btn {...props} ref={args[1]} />
    } else {
        const {kind, ...props} = args[0];
        return <Div {...props} ref={args[1]} />
    }
};

export const Wrapper = forwardRef(_Wrapper);

const Foo = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
    // @ts-expect-error
    return <Wrapper ref={ref} kind={Kind.div} />
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL7YCuAzkpXAL4FQQhwDkUqGnA3AChQkWHBgBPMElxwAwu0gA7JEpgAFNmFrYAYsVJkkFJFTgAJACoBZADIBBGDCjAARtRhJazVuy490GAFBQTQIJVp4ACEYJTgAXgIDckoAHis7KI8YcIBRABskEFUsCxsHJxd3T1p08qynPMLitQA+VoAKDrAtHTgefABKBNa4VOqcuJwAOlmeiG0WAficAZYAelbBoTCI+AARYAA3BKSoEhTTOrtDo4KikuwMiuc3Dy9r21v7lph2rvm2mwA2G8VGqTIx1ws2mgNoS1MKzWcE22xCqmoHAA0sAlGRcII4ES4K5YphCcTIUdyUwQpJpHAAOpQFBgaRQTQLWiWKRIVKWOBIAAenjx3hxeNGiQpRIAZLIANa4sgALjgApYMrg8o6AuForI4uV01JcQA-PJFOESpztKl6UgIPg4DElKM1QpwNa1Lbag6nXBblshIIHUyWWykFB7FAAOa1PUi1SGuASshSgnEuAAbTTJtiAF01dm4Wrmaz2b6edJUnnTa1gaY1fpzoZjGlng1Jj8Sq0C0Is7njVSiznS+GK1Gq7za8Pjg3+k24C2LkYTPhPt9mr3+4ImNnLLvQuFInBgLRXbbKOoUMAoKcOqR42WI+yY-HZ5LBmqn95zxPI2jONajrWIpVGX9swABgLaYlTxBJ4kSUClBDfBqCUDBgHCOAAH1y0A7pehfScOV6as+RQhcBmbZI1w7epsiaB42m-OAACkAGUAA1ph7NQhHQzCYGwuJ8NfKMiK5EjAOnGs8ypailxXNt103Y5+L+NiuN4zTBIwrCcPE0iOhhX8ZLfYDPzIfM3TgAAfADLI-BT52GHAtWAZ0OnPS8tGvW8oEfYDBncrUs12U8cHgshsBhOEWESSCYIHLNiR4GBqCgOJUldaE5l6BF8BWSCAEYCw2VotRYJB8noTM0qJSL4Gi5U4oKrlErgZLd0aokMqynLbny2FCsXYqcDKiqUSqrNaSYENhVEeBmqcqNTkIVtLnwDpjMAtFjz2ZcIAgB9QVGDyIpPeABlOOgGCuTsmKUTTOiUah8nyNEs3WdY4AAARgWgAFolqQDBQagNgoC1AbsrGAj2XGpFTBYGKVlco5Kr3fggA)

I'm still curious if there's a way to use the generic parameter, however.